# android, text to speech

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm playing with text to speech to make my testapp a little more fun. It works in the emulator but not on my phone since my default locale isn't english.

However, the texts are english so the tts should of course use english. As far as I know I can implement an autoninstall, something like

```
    public void onInit(int status) {

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        // Set preferred language to US english.

        int result = mtts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA ||
            result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
           // Lanuage data is missing or the language is not supported.
            Log.e(TAG, "Language is not available.");
        } else {

            // The TTS engine has been successfully initialized.
            speak();
        }
    } else {
        // missing data, install it
        Intent installIntent = new Intent();
        installIntent.setAction(
            TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
        startActivity(installIntent);
    }
}
```

But, do I want to? Does installing locales take a lot of space? Does it mess up something else?

regards

Comment: You could always pop up a box asking the user if they want to install the tts data.  I wouldn't be too concerned about it though.  It shouldn't mess anything up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should execute this:

```
   // missing data, install it
    Intent installIntent = new Intent();
    installIntent.setAction(
        TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
    startActivity(installIntent);
```

when you get LANG_MISSING_DATA

Answer (score 0):

I would only try the install in the case where "LANG_MISSING_DATA" not for "LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED". Since it starts another activity and the user can choose whether they download it or not, I wouldn't worry too much about it taking space. No, it shouldn't mess anything up.

Answer (score 0):

Android allows you convert your text into voice. Not only you can convert it but it also allows you to speak text in variety of different languages.
Android provides TextToSpeech class for this purpose.
For more detail please follow this tutorial :-

http://a-droidtech.blogspot.in/2015/06/android-text-to-speech-tutorial-android.html